# Eclipse, GCC, installing them twice?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am thinking of installing Eclipse for developing STM32 programs (I have a question about this that I will post later). In the instructions it says I have to install:

- the IDE for C/C++
- GNU ARM Eclipse Plug-ins
- GNU GCC ARM tool-chain
  among other tools..

However, I am *also* thinking of installing e2studio for developing Renesas programs. You can see about this [Here](https://www.renesas.com/en-us/products/software-tools/tools/ide/e2studio.html). There you can see that this is "based on Eclipse CDT" (what is the difference between this CDT and the IDE?) and that it also uses Plug-ins like GNU Tool & Support [Here](https://gcc-renesas.com).

My question is, is this possible? Do I have to install them separately? (I guess so). Will the GNU tools will also be installed twice??
(I am using a windows10 machine)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

CDT is dedicated to C/C++ programming. Actually I personally prefere to have separate eclipse installations for different families of uC. Why? Because it is much easier to manage updates and to keep my work in the correct order.

For STM32 I advice (I think, you are a novice user of Eclipse & ARM toolchains) to install OpenSTM32 (yo have a straightforward installer). It imports projects from CUBEFX & MX which gives you an easy way to import examples & initialisation code from Cube. I personally do not use HAL libraries but as I know I am a minority.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I am also thinking of installing e2studio for developing
>   Renesas programs. You can see about this Here. There you can see that
>   this is "based on Eclipse CDT" (what is the difference between this
>   CDT and the IDE?)

Eclipse CDT is an open-source general-purpose C and C++ IDE.

e2studio is one of several software packages that extend CDT with (most likely proprietary) plugins geared towards a more specific market (in this case, Renesas programs).

> My question is, is this possible?

Yes.

> Do I have to install them separately? (I guess so).

Yes.

> Will the GNU tools will also be installed twice?? (I am using a windows10 machine)

You can certainly share a single installation of a toolchain between two installations of CDT, if both of them need the same toolchain (in terms of version and architecture). I don't know enough about STM32 and Renesas to tell you if they use the same toolchain.